# Wordpress intercept Submit via hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, module, hook

I want to intercept a `SUBMIT` action via `hooks`.

Basically `submit` is coming via a generic `form`

```
<from action="someurl_this_page" method="post">
<input type="text" value="some text"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
<form>
```

Need to know which trigger to access, something like:
`add_action('hook', my_method)`.

Tried with `save_post`, `the_post` , `publish_post`, `pre_post_update` but neither manage to intercept.
Since "action" is not set to `admin-post.php` cannot use `admin_post_nopriv`
No 3-rd party plugin is interesting, need something done in "clasic_way".

More over, I'm not allowed to do any changes on front-end(modify actions, field, functions, etc), just can add a module which will do the task.

Comment: _“Tried with save_post, the_post , publish_post, pre_post_update but neither manage to intercept.”_ - why _should_ any of those have worked? Your stand-alone form on its own doesn’t do any of these things.

Comment: @CBroe, was just an example of what was tried and obvious wasn't working ... don't see any fair reason to down-vote ... just need the right hook if any ???

Comment: Your form has no connection to _any_ WordPress functionality, just by itself. It will just cause a POST request to whatever URL you specified. If that is not any particular endpoint URL, but just the address of some page - then you will need to find a generic hook, that runs pretty early, and handle the POSTed data yourself in there.

Comment: @CBroe Agree : " you will need to find a generic hook, that runs pretty early, and handle the POSTed data yourself in there" but any hints ? (ok to handle post date there)

Comment: http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/ - `init` is usually a good place to do stuff you need to be done when the WP basics are loaded and initialized

Comment: @CBroe  Thx., looking over and if found something useful for submit I could accept the comment as answer.

Comment: @CBroe. `init` is just fine and fire-up. Further just read `$_REQUEST` in order get the data and do additional processing. Kindly post the answer to validate. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no connection to any WordPress functionality, just by itself. It will just cause a POST request to whatever URL you specified. If that is not any particular endpoint URL, but just the address of some page - then you will need to find a generic hook, that runs pretty early, and handle the POSTed data yourself in there.

`init` is usually a good place to do stuff you need to be done when the WP basics are loaded and initialized

http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/